Images not displaying in CollectionView in .NET MAUI
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application where I'm trying to display a list of images in a CollectionView. Despite following the documentation, my images are not being displayed. Here is the code for my MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs.
MainPage.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.NFT.Marketplace.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
            <Image Source="{Binding .}"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   WidthRequest="137"
                   HeightRequest="137">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <RoundRectangleGeometry
                        Rect="0,0,137,137"
                        CornerRadius="16" />
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>       
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="CollectionView">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsLayout">
                <LinearItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    ItemSpacing="14"/>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

MainPage.xaml.cs:
namespace Maui.NFT.Marketplace
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GenerateData();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void GenerateData()
        {
            ImageList = new List<string>();

            for (var i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
            {
                ImageList.Add($"ima{i.ToString("00")}.png");
            }
        }
    }
}

Project Structure:

The images ima01.png to ima18.png are in the root Resources\Images folder.
Each image file's Build Action is set to Content, and Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if newer.

Issue:
The CollectionView displays the correct number of items (18), but no images are shown. Instead, I get empty spaces where the images should be. I verified that the BindingContext is set correctly and the list of image paths is populated as expected.
What I've Tried:

Verified the image files are correctly included in the project and set with the correct properties.
Checked the output directory to ensure the images are being copied.
Simplified the XAML and code-behind to focus on displaying a single CollectionView.
Confirmed there are no errors or warnings in the output console.

Question:
What could be causing the images to not display in the CollectionView, and how can I resolve this issue?
Checked Image Inclusion in Project:
Ensured the image files are included in the project.
Set the Build Action of the images to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer.
Verified Output Directory:
After building the project, confirmed that the images are present in the output directory.
Simplified XAML and C# Code:
Created a simplified version of MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs to focus on displaying a single CollectionView.
Checked Output Console:
Confirmed that there are no errors or warnings in the output console indicating issues with loading the images.
What I Expected:
I expected the images to be displayed correctly within the CollectionView, filling the screen with the provided images.

Thanks for high quality of the question structure and information, confirm you have included images on the project properties like , and do rebuild 2 times, if not working I'm going to try it and provide you with the answer if I success

From the docs “ Images can be added to your app project by dragging them to the Resources\Images folder of your project, where its build action will automatically be set to MauiImage”


Each image file's Build Action is set to Content, and Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if newer.

This is the issue your build action should be MauiImage, do this and then rebuild and it will start working as long as your names are correct.
Feel free to reach out if this does not work
